# Booting Linux from encrypted root parition without initrd/initramfs

Tags: linux, boot, luks, initramfs

Booting Linux without initrd/initramfs works OK when you have simple MBR/GPT partitions, you simply append `root=/dev/device` and you're good to go given that your kernel contains the modules required to work with your storage.

Has anyone attempted or achieved the same when the root partition is encrypted using LUKS? If you have accomplished that, please share the details.

Answer (score 1):

When you use LUKS, you will need some kind of user interface component that will request the encryption passphrase from the user... or otherwise gets the needed key data needed to unlock the encryption, by e.g. using a smart card, a keyfile on a specific removable media, or a TPM chip.

The vanilla Linux kernel does not have the user interface for any of this, as interacting with user(s) is easier done with user-space code. As a result, the use of initrd/initramfs is effectively mandatory with an encrypted root filesystem.

If you are using a bootloader that can handle encryption (e.g. a reasonably up-to-date version of GRUB) then you can also encrypt the location where the initramfs file lives.

For added security, you could even keep your `/boot` as a separate partition on a bootable removable media, and use that media as the "ignition key" to your computer, effectively making it an extra authentication factor.